# Trigger mouse wheel scroll event - puppeteer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, testing

I have a script in which I need to test the scrolling functionality on my page.  I have two scroll bars, one for the browser window and another for my grid in which I have implemented infinite scroll.  I am testing the browser window scroll like so:

```
(async () => {

    const innerWidth = await page.evaluate(_ => { return window.innerWidth} );
    const innerHeight = await page.evaluate(_ => { return window.innerHeight} );
    const mouse = page.mouse
    await mouse.move(innerWidth/2, innerHeight/2);

    await page.waitFor(500);

    // Scroll Window
    page.evaluate(_ => {
        window.scrollBy(0, innerHeight);
    });     
    ...
}();
```

This works fine for the window scroll, however, I cannot use this to test the mouse wheel scroll in the grid.  I understand that there is a way to create a mouse wheel event in JQuery like so:

```
$(".testdiv").on('mousewheel', function(e){
  console.log(e);

})
var event = jQuery.Event( "mousewheel" );
event.deltaY = -1;
$(".testdiv").trigger(event);
```

I need to do this in pure JS.  Is there a way to implement this in my script with pure JS?

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is to use pure JS to implement mousewheel, and test it; i.e. invoke custom events.

In order to add a mouse wheel listener

```
yourdomNode.addEventListener('mousewheel', ()=>{
    //Some mousewheel listener
});
```

And if you would like to send a custom event, which is intended for testing, you can do as below. You can certainly add more information to the created event that can match your test purposes.

```
var cEvent = new Event('mousewheel');

cEvent.detail = 0;
cEvent.wheelDeltaY = someWheelDeltaY;
cEvent.wheelDeltaX = someWeelDeltaX;

if (cEvent.wheelDeltaY) {
  cEvent.wheelDelta = somewheelDeltaY;
} else if (cEvent.wheelDeltaX) {
  cEvent.wheelDelta = someWheelDeltaX;
}

yourdomNode.dispatchEvent(cEvent);
```

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the general principle, I am creating a custom event.  However, I am not sure how this would work in my specific case.  All I need to do is move my mouse to a specific point in the page, like so: `await mouse.move(innerWidth/2, innerHeight/2);` and then trigger a mouse scroll event.  In other words, it is not tied to a specific DOM node.

Comment: Whoever is reading my comment, I will be really happy to find that I am mistaken because I have been searching this for a long time. You cannot control mouse or keyboards as per se in your browser. What you can do is to create custom events, and trigger them via dom nodes. Make sure that this will go through the pipeline of your event listeners.